# Why am I getting Int object is not iterable error? What approach should i follow if I get such errors next time?

Tags: python, arrays, error-handling, return, iterable

This is my code:

```
def gradingStudents(grades):
    for i in range(len(grades) n):

       if grades[i]>38 and grades[i]%5==(3 or 4):
           if(grades[i]%5==3):
              grades[i]=(grades[i]+2)
           else:
              grades[i]=(grades[i]+1)

       else:
           grades[i]=grades[i]
       return grades[i]
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve], which should include how you call this function and with what arguments.

Comment: And as you're programming in Python, are you sure about the indentation of the code you show? Is the `return` statement really *inside* the loop? Also check the condition in the `if`, `grades[i]%5==(3 or 4)` won't do what you think.

Comment: And this shouldn't really need to be said, but write your question *inside* the actual question body, and make the title a short summary of the question or problem.

Comment: Thankx for the suggestion will keep that in mind for the next time. Actually I am new to python and stack overflow thats why.

Answer (score 0):

1. `for i in range(len(grades) n):` - remove the n
2. grades[i]%5==(3 or 4): - this won't work like this. You can rewrite as `(grades[i]%5==3 or grades[i]%5==4)`